# Using Typesafe Config's ConfigFactory to set key setting in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt.version=**0.13.1**

In `build.sbt` I am assigning a setting key by calling a piece of my project dependency's code that in turn configures itself via Typesafe Config's `ConfigFactory`. My dependency has a `reference.conf` in the root of the jar, and my project itself contains an overriding `application.conf` in `src/main/resources`.

The lib/dependency is also my code, btw.

```
import com.mylib.Finders
import com.myproj.sbt.Keys._

projKeyColorSetting in Compile := Finders.findColor // this calls ConfigFactory.load

seq(projSettings:_*)
```

The build doesn't even load because it can't find the first conf key I attempt to reference in my lib code.

I've tried a number of combinations of scoping and Classpath manipulation in my build file, but to no avail. I assumed that the jar's `reference.conf` would have been on the `Compile` scope's classpath but it doesn't work as I expect.

I spent the majority of yesterday poring over SBT documentation on Classpath, Scopes, Keys, Tasks, and ResourceGenerators - my intention is to execute a custom plugin that relies on  the `projKeyColorSetting` setting in `build.sbt` as follows:

```
lazy val projSettings = inConfig(Compile) {
    Seq(
        resourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task {
            val fileCreated = createColorFile(projKeyColorSetting.value)
            Seq(fileCreated)
        }
    )
 }
```

Comment: what isn't clear to me here is how com.myproj.app.Foo got on the sbt classpath in the first place - classes compiled from src/main/scala are not automatically available in build.sbt unless you did something to make them available - you need to do that same thing with src/main/resources ? The build code (build.sbt) normally does not have the app's classes available in there.

Comment: Thanks Havoc - I tried to oversimplify my example, and have updated it to reflect more of who my build exists. I'm not calling project application code in build.sbt, but code from one of my dependency's (which I also control). I do want to read my project's configuration under _src/main/resources_, however, which is not on the default Classpath as you've confirmed for me.

What I'd like to know is:

1. Why my dependency's **reference.conf** isn't being found, and
2. How to add _src/main/resources_ within scope of my setting key assignment or plugin

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Also read the order in which the configuration values are overridden: https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting a class from foo.jar, then `ConfigFactory.load()` should get a reference.conf found in the same jar. If it doesn't, then something is wrong but it's hard to guess what. It could be that reference.conf has some invalid syntax in it possibly; it could be that reference.conf isn't in the jar; it could be that reference.conf is in a subdirectory instead of root of the jar; hard to guess. I'd try `-Dconfig.trace=loads` to look for problems in there (it should tell you whether config tries to load the reference.conf for example). You could also do your own `classLoader.getResources` and see if you can find the file without config involved.
You could also try `ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("reference")` and see if your reference settings are in there, and try calling `ConfigFactory.load` directly and see if your settings are in there. Just in general, double-check all assumptions and see where it goes wrong.

As for how to add src/main/resources, the two basic strategies would be 1) to get it on the classpath somehow (which is probably difficult in this case; you would need it before even launching sbt or would need to do some kind of custom ClassLoader fun) or probably more practical 2) load it manually with `ConfigFactory.parseFile()`.

I would probably grab the `resourceDirectory` key as a dependency of your task and then do something like (untested):

```
myTask := {
   val resourceDir = (resourceDirectory in Compile).value
   val appConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(resourceDir / "application.conf")
   val config = ConfigFactory.load(appConfig) // puts reference.conf underneath
   Finders.findColor(config)
}
```

Note that this involves changing findColor to take a `Config` parameter, or maybe you would prefer to make Finders a non-singleton that can be constructed with a `Config`; see the example at https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/examples/scala/simple-lib/src/main/scala/simplelib/SimpleLib.scala#L22 where I was trying to illustrate that when using a `Config` usually a library should both default to `ConfigFactory.load` but also have a constructor that allows a custom `Config` for situations like this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, re: **-Dconfig.trace=loads**.

I changed my _projKeyColorSetting_ to a _projKeyColorTask_ so that at least I can load my project in sbt and delay the error until I run the **package** command.

I am trying to add the **resourceDirectory** to the **fullClasspath** right before I call .value on the setting in hopes that my dependency code will find my **application.conf**, but it's still not working. Code to follow:

Comment: lazy val projSettings = inConfig(Compile) {
        Seq(
            resourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task {
                // modify classpath
                fullClasspath in Compile += Attributed.blank((resourceDirectory in Compile).value)
                // execute task and run dependency's code
                val fileCreated = createColorFile(projKeyColorKey.value)
                Seq(fileCreated)
            }
        )
    }

Comment: My problem has been a sort of perfect storm of learning how plugins, project/* build files, tasks, scopes, etc work with sbt. I was hardcoding **resourceDirectory** in _project/Plugin.scala_ which was giving me the wrong resource directory.. so now I'm referencing the parent project's correctly. I'm still trying to add it to **fullClasspath** and I'm still coming up short on finding the **application.conf** file.

Comment: Remember that for project foo the classpath and deps are in foo/*.sbt and foo/project/*.scala. The build itself is also a project so the build for foo has its deps and classpath defined in foo/project/*.sbt and foo/project/project/*.scala. So the .sbt files in foo/project refer to the build program and the .scala files in foo/project refer to the foo program.

Comment: And yes there is a build build and a build build build it just keeps recursing until our brains melt.Type "reload plugins" to recurse one build at the interactive prompt and "reload return" to pop back out. You can then use "show fullClasspath" and stuff to inspect the build program.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in sbt.

Here's my understanding of your use case and how sbt ultimately behaved.

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.5-M2
```

The folder **config-only-project** is for a project with the following two files - **build.sbt** and **src/main/resources/application.conf**. This is to simulate an external dependency on a project with `application.conf` inside.

**build.sbt** in `config-only-project`

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.0"
```

**src/main/resources/application.conf** in `config-only-project`

```
app-name {
  hello = "Hello from Typesafe Config"
}
```

The following files configure the default `plugins` project as well as the build configuration itself (and hence the build for the project under investigation).

**project/build.sbt**

```
lazy val configOnlyProject = uri("../config-only-project")

lazy val plugins = project in file(".") dependsOn (configOnlyProject)
```

**project/build.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import com.typesafe.config._

object build extends Build {
  lazy val mySetting = taskKey[String]("Setting using Typesafe Config")
  lazy val myS = mySetting := {
    // Compiler issue Config conf???
    println((fullClasspath in Compile).value)
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
    conf getString "app-name.hello"
  }
  lazy val configOnlyProject = uri("config-only-project")
  lazy val root = project in file(".") settings (myS) dependsOn (configOnlyProject)
}
```

This gives the following directory structure:

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/setting-typesafe-config
$ tree
.
├── config-only-project
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── project
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               └── application.conf
└── project
    ├── application.conf
    ├── build.properties
    ├── build.sbt
    └── build.scala

6 directories, 6 files
```

What I couldn't understand was that the setting itself didn't work - neither for the main project nor for the `plugins` project.

```
> mySetting
List(Attributed(/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/setting-typesafe-config/target/scala-2.10/classes), Attributed(/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/setting-typesafe-config/config-only-project/target/scala-2.10/classes), Attributed(/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar), Attributed(/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.2.0.jar))
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last root/*:mySetting for the full output.
[error] (root/*:mySetting) com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'app-name'
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 31, 2014 10:24:12 PM
```

The error was as follows:

```
> last root/*:mySetting
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'app-name'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:147)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:206)
    at build$$anonfun$myS$1.apply(build.scala:11)
    at build$$anonfun$myS$1.apply(build.scala:7)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (root/*:mySetting) com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'app-name'
```

It did work when I executed the same code in the Scala console:

```
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import com.typesafe.config._
import com.typesafe.config._

scala> ConfigFactory.load()
res0: com.typesafe.config.Config = ...
scala> res0 getString "app-name.hello"
res1: String = Hello from Typesafe Config
```

When I switched to the `plugins` project it worked fine, too:

```
> reload plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/setting-typesafe-config/project
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import com.typesafe.config._
import com.typesafe.config._

scala> ConfigFactory.load()
res0: com.typesafe.config.Config = ...
scala> res0 getString "app-name.hello"
res1: String = Hello from Typesafe Config
```

I wish I could explain it, but it seems too much cognitive load for me :(

Comment: What if you use an explicit ClassLoader for val conf = ConfigFactory.load()?

Comment: That's what worked for the OP in the other question and I asked him to update my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720360/i-need-to-load-application-conf-via-typesafes-configfactory-within-an-sbt-task#comment34716939_22720360 -(guess I'll have to do it myself in a few days).

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with a Play project, solved by adding a `ClassLoader` parameter to `ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax()` in the task definition:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    myTask := {
      val cl = new java.net.URLClassLoader(Array((resourceDirectory 
        in Compile).value.toURI.toURL))
      // load ./conf/foo.conf
      val config = ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax(cl, "foo.conf")
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I had with sbt 1.4.4 is that I was trying to add a dependency in my meta-build (`project/build.sbt`) so that I could use it in my main build.

The library was using `ConfigFactory.load()` which uses the ClassLoader from the current thread which ended up being [SbtMetaClassLoader](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.4.x/main/src/main/java/sbt/internal/MetaBuildLoader.java) which did not have the loaders for the meta-build dependencies.

The fix was to change the library to use `ConfigFactory.load(getClass.getClassLoader)` so that it was using the class loader that loaded the class from the library and presumably the rest of the JAR including the `reference.conf` file.