# I need to load application.conf via typesafe's ConfigFactory within an sbt Task

Tags: scala, classpath, sbt, config

I have a simple project here:

https://github.com/bloo/foo-gen-config/

.. that does one thing - load sbt and runs the task *foo-gen*, which fails.

The Task def is here:

https://github.com/bloo/foo-gen-config/blob/master/project/FooConfigPlugin.scala#L19-L25

(I alluded to this question along with a number of other convoluted issues here: [How to make a sbt task use a specific configuration scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845176/how-to-make-a-sbt-task-use-a-specific-configuration-scope) but have since distilled it down to a single issue I need help with)

I am open to suggestions on how to handle this, but I definitely want to keep *application.conf* in *src/main/resources*. Thanks!

Quickstart:

```
git clone https://github.com/bloo/foo-gen-config.git
cd foo-gen-config/
sbt foo-gen
```

**$35 Bounty**

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1450100-how-to-load-application-conf-via-typesafe-s-configfactory-within-an-sbt-task

Comment: I haven't gotten it to work in my real project, but defining a URLClassLoader in this test project works so I know I'm on the right track.

https://github.com/bloo/foo-gen-config/commit/fe8ad400db240695e87e75c9464f2f8d1249d109

Comment: You should really close the question after you merge it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663213/using-typesafe-configs-configfactory-to-set-key-setting-in-build-sbt. It's a duplicate. Hint: you could then edit my answer with the classpath trick and approve.